Unable to Resize Partition in Xubuntu VM Due to Busy Target
I am trying to resize the main partition of my Xubuntu virtual machine (VM) running on VMware, but I encounter an error stating that the target is busy when attempting to unmount it. Despite several attempts and troubleshooting steps, I have been unable to proceed.
System Details:
Host System: Windows 11
Virtual Machine Software: VMware Workstation 17.5.x
Guest OS: Xubuntu 24.04 LTS
ISO Used for Live Environment: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Initial Setup:
Installed Xubuntu 24.04 LTS on a VMware virtual machine.
Attempted to resize the main partition containing all files.
Live Environment Setup:
Downloaded the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ISO.
Created a new VM using this ISO to access the live environment. Successfully booted into the live environment.
GParted Usage:
Launched GParted to resize the partition.
Encountered the error: Could not unmount /dev/sda3: target is busy.
Unmounting Attempt:
1.Attempted to unmount using the terminal: sudo umount /dev/sda3
2.Received error: umount: /: target is busy.
Identifying Busy Processes:

Ran sudo fuser -m /dev/sda3 to identify busy processes.
Received a list of process IDs (PIDs) indicating the partition is in use.

Alternative Attempts:

Tried lazy unmount: sudo umount -l /dev/sda3

Error persisted with the partition remaining busy.


Recovery Mode:
Attempted to boot into recovery mode using GRUB: Restarted VM, pressed Shift and Esc keys repeatedly but did not access GRUB menu.
System booted directly to the login screen.
Checking Disk Options:

Ensured correct disk was selected in VM settings. Verified that the disk file format is .vmdk.

Adding VHD to New VM: Added the existing Xubuntu VHD to the new VM running Ubuntu live environment.

Attempted to resize the partition using GParted in this new VM setup. Encountered the same issue with the partition being busy.


Current State:
Booted into Ubuntu live environment.
Still unable to unmount or resize the busy partition.
Request for Assistance:
I need help with:

Safely unmounting the busy partition to allow resizing.

Any alternative methods to resize the main partition without data loss.

Suggestions for accessing GRUB recovery mode successfully in a VM environment.


Thank you for your assistance!

Use Live CD or just boot the Ubuntu installation ISO in live mode.
